# passing string from an activity to a fragment

Tags: java, android

Hi ive been going through questions and found a solution to pass a string from an activity (not the fragment activity) to a fragment. i want to pass a document ID on click from RestaurantsList.class to Mainsfragment.class, inside my onclick.

The error message i get is the following:

*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.app.Activity.getIntent()' on a null object reference*

here is my code for the activity:

```
package com.example.hostapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.hostapp.Adapters.RestaurantAdapter;
import com.example.hostapp.Adapters.categoryCardAdapter;
import com.example.hostapp.MenuFragments.MainsFragment;
import com.example.hostapp.Models.Restaurant;
import com.example.hostapp.Models.categoryCard;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class RestaurantList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference restaurantref = db.collection("restaurants");
    private RestaurantAdapter adapter;

    String categoryid = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurant_list);


        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {


        //Get intent
        if (getIntent() != null)
            categoryid = getIntent().getStringExtra("categoryid");
        if (!categoryid.isEmpty() && categoryid != null) {
            Query query = restaurantref.whereEqualTo("categoryid", categoryid).orderBy("name");

            final FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Restaurant> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Restaurant>().setQuery(query, Restaurant.class).build();

            adapter = new RestaurantAdapter(options);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.restaurant_recycler);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.setOnItemClickListerner(new RestaurantAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                    Restaurant restaurant = documentSnapshot.toObject(Restaurant.class);
                    Intent foodlist = new Intent(RestaurantList.this, Foodlist.class);


                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("restaurantid", documentSnapshot.getId());
                    MainsFragment m4 = new MainsFragment();
                    m4.setArguments(bundle);


                    //foodlist.putExtra("restaurantid", documentSnapshot.getId());
                    startActivity(foodlist);


                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

here is my code for the fragment:

```
package com.example.hostapp.MenuFragments;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.hostapp.Adapters.FoodAdapter;
import com.example.hostapp.Models.FoodModel;
import com.example.hostapp.R;
import com.example.hostapp.RestaurantList;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;


public class MainsFragment extends Fragment {


    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private FoodAdapter adapter;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mains, container, false);

        String restaurantNumber = getArguments().getString("restaurantid");
        Query menuref = db.collectionGroup("Foods").whereEqualTo("menuid", restaurantNumber);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FoodModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FoodModel>().
                setQuery(menuref, FoodModel.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FoodAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_mains);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return view;
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting intent to foodlist activity without any extras! it's not related to fragment.
there is no interaction between your bundle and intent!
can you explain the flow path the from RestaurantList to the fragment?

Comment: i see, from the Restaurant List, you are taken to the Foodlist activity, this activity is the one that has 3 fragments (Mains, Starts and Dessert fragments) that i want to pass the information from RestaurantList to. so i basically want to send a document snapshot from RestaurantsList to the fragments of another activity (Foodlist)

Comment: I will explain more as an answer. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same experience like this. Here is how I handled it:

1, Pass your data from RestaurantList activity to your foodlist activity via intent.putExtra();

```
Intent foodlist = new Intent(RestaurantList.this, Foodlist.class);
foodlist.putExtra("restaurantid", documentSnapshot.getId());
startActivity(foodlist);
```

2, Get the value by getIntent() from Foodlist activity;

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("restaurantid");
```

3, Pass your data to the Adapter where you are initializing the adapter. (sth like this :)

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(),id);
```

4, Get the data in constractor of adapter (you have to create a global variable and fill it in constructor) and create a bundle in getItem() method and pass the data to it and set arguments to the fragment (like below code)

```
public class YourAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    String id;
    public AdapterPagerShift(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs, String id) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("restaurantid", documentSnapshot.getId());
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                MainsFragment main = new MainsFragment();
                main.setArguments(bundle);
                return main;
            case 1:
                //...
            case 2:
               //...
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

5, Get the data by using below code in your MainsFragment class :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        String id = getArguments().getString("restaurantid");

}
```

Hope it helps!